# How do I see if my Android Nexus received the latest security updates?

Tags: updates, security, ota-update, 5.1-lollipop

I'd like to check the patch level of my Nexus. I'm using Lollipop 5.1.1 build LMY48I. Under 'System updates' in 'About phone', it says 'Your system is up to date'. Should I assume that includes security updates?

Answer (score 3):

In Marshmallow (Android 6.0) there will be an additional bit of information on the 'About' screen showing the "Android security patch level". This should show the date of the last security update that your phone has. How you will know that this is the latest available is unclear though.

[Source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/09/29/android-now-shows-your-devices-android-security-patch-level-in-marshmallow/)

As for pre-Marshmallow the best suggestion I have is to look at the [factory images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) page and see what the latest build number is for your device. Depending on which device you have there should be a newer version than LMY48I, most likely build LMY48M.

Answer (score 1):

The Build number, e.g. `LMY48I` (found in 'About phone') can be looked up in the [Android Security Updates](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-security-updates) list, or the list of [Android factory images](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images).

In this case you can see `LMY48I` refers to the August 2015 security update, but there has been another update since then: `LMY48M` for September.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Android Device Protection (ADP), then according to Google,

> applies only to devices running Android 5.1 or higher that came
>   preinstalled with Android 5.0 or higher, such as Nexus 6 and Nexus 9.

References ..[here](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6172890?hl=en) and [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/03/09/google-officially-announces-android-5-1-rollout-starts-today-dual-sim-support-hd-voice-and-device-protection/).

Comment: No, not for the anti-theft. Google started pushing out monthly security updates this year.

Comment: My bad, according to Google, this update was made to patch the Stagefright exploit, and if you want to check if your device vulnerable or not, then you can use one of this apps, 1. Stagefright Detector ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zimperium.stagefrightdetector ), 2. Stagefright Detector ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.stagefrightdetector&hl=de ), everything you need to know about Stagefright in this article ( https://www.androidpit.com/what-is-stagefright-on-android-am-i-affected-and-what-can-i-do ).

Comment: Cheers. I was hoping for an easier way to check for future security updates as well.